# I installed Hadoop 3.2.0. and Hive and getting following error

Tags: hive, installation

I installed Hadoop 3.2.0. and Hive and getting the following error.

`hadoopusr@shiv-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB:~/ecosystem/hive/bin$ schematool -initSchema -dbType derby`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.2.0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:169)
```

Answer (score 0):

hadoop 3.2.0 is not compatible with hive 2.1.0. the error is due to version incompatibility.

this is resolved by installing Hive 2.3.5 along with hadoop 3.2.0 and Java 1.8.0_211